# Racket Equations in a List of Strings

Tags: racket

I am using DrRacket and I have a list of strings. One possible input could be '("+" "100" "22"). How do I get these list functions to execute properly? The answer to my example would be 122. I could do it if I could remove the fact that the input has to be a list of strings. 
So, how do I change a list of strings to a list of symbols?

Comment: Is there only ever one operator? (ie, +,-,* or /). And if so, is the operator always the first string in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something similar to:

```
#lang racket

(define (evaluate expr)
  (define r evaluate)
  (match expr
    [(and (? string?) (app string->number n)) 
     n]
    [(list "+" e1 e2)  (+ (r e1) (r e2))]
    [(list "-" e1 e2)  (- (r e1) (r e2))]
    [(list "*" e1 e2)  (* (r e1) (r e2))]
    [(list "/" e1 e2)  (/ (r e1) (r e2))]   
    [_ 
     (error 'evaluate "got ~a" expr)]))

(evaluate '("+" "1" "2"))
(evaluate '("+" ("-" "5" "4") "2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a list of strings to a list of symbols with the `map` function.

For example:

```
(define los '("+" "100" "22))
(map string->symbol los)
```